# How Do I Create A Button That Toggles States?

Tags: javascript, button, methods, dom-events

I want to create a button, that when clicked, changes its name and function. The button is called 'Expand', and when clicked it allows a div to expand. Once clicked, I want it to change its functionality and text to 'shrink', where it then shrinks a div.

```
let expandButton = document.createElement(`button`);
expandButton.setAttribute(`class`, `listButton`);
expandButton.textContent = `+`

if (expandButton.className == `listButton`) {
  expandButton.addEventListener(`click`, (e) => {
    expandButton.setAttribute(`class`, `listButtonClicked`);
  })
}

if (expandButton.className == `listButtonClicked`) {
  console.log(`active`);
  expandButton.addEventListener(`click`, (e) => {
    expandButton.setAttribute(`class`, `listButton`);
  })
}
```

When the button is clicked, it only expands. Upon being clicked again, it doesn't do anything; the `console.log` line in the second area doesn't even register.

Comment: Given your mention of a `render()` function I'm going to assume you're using React...?

Comment: Use the [ClassList API](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) instead of checking the `className` property incorrectly and setting the `class` attribute manually.

Comment: You’re only binding a single event listener based on the _initial_ state. Instead, use a single event listener on `expandButton` and check its state _inside_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yesterday, I wrote a very similar answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74250060/how-can-i-achieve-show-more-text-just-like-youtube/74250370#74250370). I've updated my code to include a "show less" button:

```js
for (const el of document.getElementsByClassName('shorten')) {
  const text = el.textContent;
  const summary = text.substring(0, 70) + '... ';
  el.textContent = summary;

  const showmore = document.createElement('span');
  showmore.textContent = 'Show more';
  showmore.style.fontWeight = 'bold';
  
  const showless = document.createElement('span');
  showless.textContent = 'Show less';
  showless.style.fontWeight = 'bold';
  
  showmore.addEventListener('click', () => {
    el.textContent = text;
    el.append(showless);
  });
  
  showless.addEventListener('click', () => {
    el.innerHTML = "";
    el.textContent = summary;
    el.append(showmore);
  });

  el.append(showmore);
}
```

```css
/* just for demostration purposes. not actually needed */

.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: lightgray;
  overflow: auto;
  margin: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="box shorten">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse ac elementum nunc. Cras vehicula, ante nec iaculis semper, mi justo ornare ipsum, ac sollicitudin tortor tellus at magna. In augue.
</div>

<div class="box shorten">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse ac elementum nunc. Cras vehicula, ante nec iaculis semper, mi justo ornare ipsum, ac sollicitudin tortor tellus at magna. In augue.
</div>

<div class="shorten">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse ac elementum nunc. Cras vehicula, ante nec iaculis semper, mi justo ornare ipsum, ac sollicitudin tortor tellus at magna. In augue.
</div>
```

It should also be noted that there is a [`<summary>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/summary) tag that does something similar. However this will not work in your case because you want to dynamically shorten the page.

Comment: I was just typing a similar answer, but Michal M. answers covers it perfectly. One thing you may want to note is that the reason your code does not work is that Event Listeners do not attach themselves retroactively, so you have to other reattach them on every change, or (as this solution suggest) add a different object that has the Listener already attached